# Navbar is not coming in pug

Tags: html, css, pug, backend

I am a beginner and trying to put my navbar as permanent in base layout. I am using youtube for it but as I am learning back end and according to my course, the navbar should appear as permanent irrespective of the changes in the linked pages in the site but it is not working.[image: It is looking like this.]

Base Layout File

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title DevilisHere
    block scripts
    block style

  Body
    block content
            nav#navbar
                    div#container
                        img(src = "../static/bg.png")
                            ul
                                li #[a(href = "/") Home]
                                li #[a(href = "/") Devil] 
                                li #[a(href = "/") Devils Address]
                                li #[a(href = "/") Contact Devil]
                    div#logotag
                        h6  DevilIsHere
           
    block foot
        footer.foot
            h3.headline Copyright © 2020 DevilisHere | All Rights Reserved
```

Home File //

```
extends layout.pug

block scripts
    script(src="../static/index.js")

block style
       style
        include ../static/navbar.css
        include ../static/section1.css 
        include ../static/section2.css
        include ../static/section3.css 
        include ../static/footer.css

block content   
        section#firstSection
            div.heading1 
                p.headline Welcome to Devils Mansion
            div.tag2 
                p Come Prepared To Die

        section#secondSection
            p.headline.head2 Opt For a Remembrable Death.
            div.heading2 
                div.card
                    h3.headline.cardhead Specialised in Peaceful Death 
                    img(src= "../static/sec21.jpg")
                    div.para 
                        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id debitis soluta neque ducimus ad. Repudiandae error rerum recusandae dolore temporibus!
                div.card
                    h3.headline.cardhead Have killed Billions
                    img(src= "../static/sec22.jpg")
                    div.para 
                        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id debitis soluta neque ducimus ad. Repudiandae error rerum recusandae dolore temporibus!
                div.card
                    h3.headline.cardhead Experienced in Breaking Bones
                    img(src= "../static/sec23.jpg")
                    div.para 
                        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id debitis soluta neque ducimus ad. Repudiandae error rerum recusandae dolore temporibus!
                div.card
                    h3.headline.cardhead Extra Caution with Body Art
                    img(src= "../static/sec24.jpg")
                    div.para 
                        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id debitis soluta neque ducimus ad. Repudiandae error rerum recusandae dolore temporibus!
                

        section#thirdSection
            h3.headline.logohead You can Submit Your Death Requests Here.
            div.logosection
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo1.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo2.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo3.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo4.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo5.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo1.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo2.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo3.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo4.png")
                div.logo 
                    img(src= "../static/logo5.png")
```

In the above code Navbar is not showing when loading the file in browser even the navbar is being in the base layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs about [Template Inheritance](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html).

`nav#navbar` is a default content.

```
...
Body
    block content
            nav#navbar
...
```

But it's getting over written by `section#firstSection`

```
...
block content   
        section#firstSection
...
```

Restructure and place `nav#navbar` as a sibling of `block content`:

```
doctype html
html
head
    title DevilisHere
    block scripts
    block style

Body
    
    nav#navbar
        div#container
            img(src = "../static/bg.png")
                ul
                    li #[a(href = "/") Home]
                    li #[a(href = "/") Devil] 
                    li #[a(href = "/") Devils Address]
                    li #[a(href = "/") Contact Devil]
        div#logotag
            h6  DevilIsHere

    block content
        
    block foot
        footer.foot
            h3.headline Copyright © 2020 DevilisHere | All Rights Reserved
```